# C++ Event Handling - issue with const

Tags: c++, events, static, handler

I already asked about my Problem, now I'm on the next Step. In the code below I have the Problem, that I always have to make the EventHandler (Server::HandleMessage) static. But I need to have it non static to access other Variables in the Server class from within the Handler.

How can I achieve this?

Here my Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

class Client{
    public:
        struct MessageReceiveArgs {
            MessageReceiveArgs(int ID, const std::string& Text) : ID(ID), Text(Text) {}
            int ID;
            std::string Text;
        };

        std::function<void(MessageReceiveArgs)> onMessageReceive;
        Client(){}

        void FireEvent(){
            this->onMessageReceive(MessageReceiveArgs(16, "SomeText"));
        }
};

class Server{
    public:
        int i;

        Server(){
            this->client.onMessageReceive = &Server::HandleMessage;
            this->i = 5;
        }

        void FireEvent(){
            this->client.FireEvent();
        }

        Client client;

        static void HandleMessage(Client::MessageReceiveArgs args) {
            std::cout<<"ID "<<args.ID<<": "<<" "<<args.Text<<std::endl;

            //need it non static
            //std::cout<<"I: "<<this->i<<std::endl;
        }
};

int main() {
    Server sv = Server();
    sv.FireEvent();
}
```

As mentioned in my earlier Post, i'm new to Standard C++ (Unix).

Comment: Note: Save yourself a copy-ctor;  pass `Text` to `MessageReceiveArgs` as a `const std::string&`. And this: `this->client = Client();` is useless. The `client` member is already default-constructed by the time you reach this code. This isn't Java or C#.

Comment: Already changed, thank you, but this doesn't solve my starting problem, you got an idea for that?

Comment: yeah, actually I do. you need a ptr-to-member and a `this` as part of your initialization of a client, or a bound-function; either will work. old-school the former, new-school the later. I'll try and write something up unless someone gets there ahead of me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly sure this is what you're after. You need to bind the implicit `this` explicitly when invoking a pointer-to-member through `std::function` in the fashion you seem to desire.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

class Client{
public:

    struct MessageReceiveArgs
    {
        MessageReceiveArgs(int ID, const std::string& Text) 
            : ID(ID), Text(Text) {}
        int ID;
        std::string Text;
    };

    Client(){}

    void FireEvent()
    {
        this->onMessageReceive(MessageReceiveArgs(16, "SomeText"));
    }

    std::function<void(MessageReceiveArgs)> onMessageReceive;
};



class Server
{
public:
    int i;

    Server()
    {
        this->client.onMessageReceive 
            = std::bind(&Server::HandleMessage, this, std::placeholders::_1);
        this->i = 5;
    }

    void FireEvent()
    {
        this->client.FireEvent();
    }

    Client client;

    void HandleMessage(Client::MessageReceiveArgs args)
    {
        std::cout<<"ID "<<args.ID<<": "<<" "<<args.Text<<std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Server sv = Server();
    sv.FireEvent();
}
```

**Output**

```
ID 16:  SomeText
```

Comment: Yiep, this is exactly what i was trying to achieve, thank you!